# Can I choose my own token values?

Tags: yacc, lex

When I make a grammar file and do a yacc -d on it, I get a y.tab.h output file.  Is there any way that I can feed the values of the tokens I want into yacc instead of it picking the values?

For example,

```
%token    FIRST_NAME
%token    LAST_NAME
...
```

produces (in y.tab.h):

```
#define   FIRST_NAME  257
#define   LAST_NAME   258
```

I know that the first 256 values are reserved for single character matches, but i would really like FIRST_NAME to be #defined as 1001 and LAST_NAME to be #defined as 1002.  What this means is that I would choose the #defines and put them into an include file before I do a yacc on the grammar file.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started reading the GNU bison manual and it said that you could do

```
%token FIRST_NAME    1001
%token LAST_NAME     1002
```

in bison and it would use these values.  I then just tried it for yacc, and it works as well.

Thanks for your time.